# How to conditionally display some widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know what is the best way to conditionally display items in a list. This is the code:

```
SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 250,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              _buildListWidget(Colors.transparent, "Kiwi"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Banana"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Pizza"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Hamburger"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Noodles"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Spinach"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Salad")
            ]),
          )
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 250,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([

             if (_chosenFood == 'fruit') {
                 _buildListWidget(Colors.transparent, "Kiwi"),
                 _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Banana")
             } else if (_chosenFood == 'fastfood') {
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Pizza"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Hamburger"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Noodles"),
             } else if (_chosenFood == 'vegetable') {
              _buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Spinach"),
              _buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Salad")
             } // if _chosenFood == 'none', show all
            ]),
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is to create a new data class that would contain the properties `color` and `name`. Something like:

```
class FoodItem {
 FoodItem(Color color, String name);
}
```

Then I would create a `_buildList` function that expects a list of FoodItem as a parameter. Something like:

```
void _buildList(List<FoodItem> items) {
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
     _buildListWidget(items[i].color, items[i].name);
   }
}
```

Now, wherever you set the _chosenFood variable you can place your logic and create the FoodItem list. This way you can have your logic separated from the actual widget building and can even write tests for it. Now in the delegate you just call `_buildList(yourItemList)`.

If you want to go even deeper you can checkout the BLoC pattern and other architectures used by other Flutter Devs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to return a good widget

```
goodWidget(_chosenFood ){
 
List returnList = [];
 if (_chosenFood == 'fruit' || _chosenFood == 'none') {
        returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.transparent, "Kiwi"));
        returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Banana"));
 } 

if (_chosenFood == 'fastfood' || _chosenFood == 'none') {
   returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Pizza"));
   returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Hamburger"));
   returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Noodles"));
 } 

if (_chosenFood == 'vegetable' || _chosenFood == 'none') {
  returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.blue, "Spinach"));
  returnList.add(_buildListWidget(Colors.purple, "Salad"));
 } 
 return returnList;
}
```

```
SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 250,
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate( goodWidget(_chosenFood )

   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum ChoosenFood {fruit, fastfood, vegetable}

SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 250,
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
               _choosenFood.createList();
            ]),
          )

extension _ChoosenFoodAddition on ChoosenFood {
   List<Widget> createList() {
     switch(this) {
       case ChoosenFood.fruit:
          _fruitList()
       case ChoosenFood.fastfood:
          _fastFoodList()
       case ChoosenFood.vegetable:
          _vegetableList()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask boolean before widget like this :

```
_choosenFood=="Fruit"? Yourwidget :_choosenFood=="FastFood"? AnotherWidget: NochoosenFood

(True or false)? YourWidget if true : YourWiget if false
```